# Use MySqlDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, dao

I'm working on an app using DAO-pattern. The connection in `MySql` is situated in my DAOFactory-Class :

```
namespace GSB
{
    class DAOFactory
    {
        private MySqlConnection connectionBDD;

       public DAOFactory()
        {
            this.InitConnexion();
        }

        public void InitConnexion()
        {

            string connexion = "SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=gsb_c#; UID=root; PASSWORD=root";
            this.connectionBDD = new MySqlConnection(connexion);
        }

        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connectionBDD.Open();
                return true;
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid UserName/Password");
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        public void deconnexion()
        {
            this.connectionBDD.Close();
        }

        public void execSqlRead(String req)
        {  //à remplir 
            this.OpenConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = this.connectionBDD.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();  //stop here
            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yolo");
                this.deconnexion();
            }

            //return myReader;
        }

        public void execSqlWrite(String req)
        {
            this.OpenConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = this.connectionBDD.CreateCommand();
            //Création d'une commande SQL en fonction de l'objet connection
            cmd.CommandText = req; //on entre la req sql
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //on ex la req
            this.deconnexion();
        }

    }
}
```

For the moment my `execSqlWrite` method is working but my `exexSqlRead` isn't because it already stopped when I want to execute my reader.
I don't know how to resolve that problem, I just want to get the results from my selected request.

How could I do it?

Comment: Your reader needs a command to execute on, you never assign anything to `cmd.CommandText` in your reader, I am assuming the `SELECT` statement is what you are passing as req, so you need `cmd.CommandText=req;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely to the Writer code, you will see that the command receives the command string. This line is missing in the reader code

```
public void execSqlRead(String req)
{  
    this.OpenConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = this.connectionBDD.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = req;
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();  //stop here
    try
    {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yolo");
        this.deconnexion();
    }

    //return myReader;
}
```

Comment: I put the missing line in my code but the app still stop with the same error = "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll"

Comment: If you look at the InnerException message you should see a more detailed error message. By the way, the error could be simply in the command text but you should add it to your question. Please [edit] it.

Comment: I think this might be helpfull : " GSB.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll"

Comment: Well, then the problem is in the connection string. (Or in the permissions set on the server for PC 127.0.0.1, I would try to use _localhost_ instead